# How To Merge 3 lists into one dictionary(with unique elements)

Tags: python

#### Code Written In Python

> `# Following Are The 3 Lists`
> `sections = ['A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B']`
> `students = ['Jack', 'Jim', 'Jack', 'Leena', 'Jim']`
> `subjects = ['Maths', 'Biology', 'Chemistry', 'English', 'Physics']`
>
> `# The Output Should Be A Dictionary`
> `classDict = {'A':{'Jack' :{1:'Maths', 2:'Chemistry'}, 'Leena':{1:'English'}}, 'B':{'Jim':{1:'Biology', 2:'Physics'}}}`

I can merge any of the two list into one dictionary, taking only first two lists in account

```
classDict = {}   
for stu in students:  
    if not stu in classDict:     
        classDict[stu] = []    
    classDict[stu].append(stu)
```

But unable to extend it to n(n=3, in my case) list.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to merge multiple lists in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5177154/how-to-merge-multiple-lists-in-python)

Comment: If either of the below helps or answers your question please up vote and accept the best one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

defualtdict and zip are your friends for this one:

I believe the following would work.

```
class_dict= defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(str)))
for (section, stu, sub) in zip(sections, students, subjects):
    l = len(class_dict[section][stu])
    class_dict[section][stu][l+1] = sub
```

you could even do this in one line if you really wanted to.

Comment: Note you have misspelled certain names.

Comment: `defaultdict` takes a function as an argument. `str` is a function, but `defaultdict(str)` is not. Perhaps you're missing a `lambda`?

Comment: Fixed as per comment by @Weeble

Comment: @MattAlcock You do not require the lambda.

Comment: @MattAlcock: if i run ur code >`KeyError: 'A'` is raised for the line `sub_dict[section][stu][l+1] = sub`

Answer (score 3):

```
from collections import defaultdict
from functools import partial
class_dict= defaultdict(partial(defaultdict,list))

for (section, student, subject) in zip(sections, students, subjects):
    class_dict[section][student].append(subject)
```

[ideone here: http://ideone.com/4xpAI ]

This has a different structure from the one you requested, because there is no reason whatsoever to have dictionaries keyed by integers, unless you are implementing a sparse array (and even then, there are better choices). If you really need that, you can convert the lists to dicts afterwards; lists are already keyed by integer.

For those who don't know, python types are callable, so wrapping object creation in a lambda is redundant.

Comment: Same comment as for Matt: I think you need a `lambda:` when calling `defaultdict` as it needs a function as an argument.

Comment: The third dimension is a dict in the question not a list although given that it is numeric sequencial keys it could be represented as such.

Comment: @MattAlcock Do you refuse to read the english parts of answers? I explicitly discuss that.

Comment: @Weeble Python types are callable.

Comment: @Marcin: under what version of Python did you run this code?  For me, the collections.defaultdict object is not callable, so `class_dict= defaultdict(defaultdict(list))` raises `TypeError: first argument must be callable`, for exactly the reason Weeble gave.

Comment: @DSM I understood the complaint to be about the use of list as a callable; code fixed accordingly.

Comment: Code works for me except that sub in the last line should be subject

Comment: @Marcin: thnx for the reply, as DCM mentioned, it raise a typeError.

Comment: @Marcin: your newer code works perfect for the students, but for the subjects, the final dictionary contains duplicates moreover, it puts 'Maths' as a subject to all the students.